# Having problems handling UIImageJPEGRepresentation or UIImagePNGRepresentation in Node.js

Tags: node.js, uiimage, alamofire, busboy, uiimagejpegrepresentation

`TL;DR:` How do you write `UIImageRepresentation` data into the actual file format in a Node.js server? (or any place outside of Swift at that)

.

.

So I'm in a bit of a predicament here...

I wanted to send a UIImageJPEGRepresentation (or any form of data encoded imagery) through Alamofire, over to a node server, to be saved there. I used Busboy to handle `MultipartFormData`...

```
  busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
  var datamail = './storage/' + fieldname;
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream(datamail)
  console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + util.inspect(val));
  console.log('Storing letter in ' + datamail);
  stream.write(val);
});
```

and save it through a write stream. I originally wanted to read a `UIImage` I had put in, but I wasn't sure how the server would respond to an object like that, so I went and used `UIImageJPEGRepresentation.` It read the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` object right...

```
Field [test.png]: value:
'�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0000d\u0000\u0000\u0000d\b\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000��\u0002\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001sRGB\u0000��\u001c�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001ciDOT\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u00002\u0000\u0000\u0000(\u0000\u0000\u00002\u0000\u0000\u00002\u0000\u0000(aj\rp�\u0000\u0000(-IDATx\u0001��\u0007T\u0014��Ǉ�\u0005X�\u0002�,u�w�+����KԈ-�\u0016[Ԩ�$1&j�I�b�\u0002��*Mz�lﻔ��م\r���s��yΜ��\u0011�����\u000e"���%S��`r�I\u0014j�Ie�OL,W��d�OM��I��%R�H�\u0019_��\u001bl�M�]�U U�\t�d2�T��\u0017H�k|��\u0013㉤�\te`]\u0002)X��O�!�\f�v�XoȿD\nn�a���?�`��\u0013R��\u001f��\u000e �_\u0007`�=:\u0010B�JozRz����\t�\u001f��\u0013X:^�CX\u000f.<9�c�\r§C��¢�$R�W?��:\u001a�L�\u0016K��\u0001\u0013H���\u000f����`�\u0013e���K\'���\u001a,+X�e\u0005�YY\u000f\u0016��A�`=\u0000�\u000f4zF�,t8t��\r�\u0005;�\b�JUz^��^Y�\t�\u001f��;�8��\u0004K\u001f�`�\u0003�wLX`�����2����e:4�|\u0007�5�L���p\u0006��ڸ��*Ē~��\u0015`�b���k\u0010����\u000fK/���t��\u0012�DD�\bbـ�\u0006�v\u0010,�T�5����tZ����\u000e�����wť����^�뿠�D���~08l-SH���$J0��\u0006�a�\u0006\u0014���\u0012��$\u0012H�������\u000e�`Xz}��a}�)=A��O����A\n\u001a�\f��ХNLt\u0018&�\u0015C�\r^:��q�Â�?\u000f�/x��z^�H�\u000b��[X@J�Ԁ\u0001)�@�\u0005^#Wh����a�ݩ-�tp�O��D�\u0001��&��ucWmDצK-5�\u0002c\'�\u0002\u0016�w�X.\u0014�ty\u0000v>A\u0006�\u0017����m��g��\u0012�����\u0002v�N6�˸\u000e��=�\u0016\u0013��Â}x\fL/Z�zX IX�W\u000e�h@J"ш\u0015=\u0000K(�\u0000,���\u0000�\u0000�\u000e\u0013���\u0018��\u0005|\u0017�a_ʱ�CGG��/I���+,�\u0013u6�\u0007a�_P\u0000E�����\u000elbP��c��\u0002T�\u0001�(u=\u0000\\�ˁ�\u0003�k\u0014�n�H)����n�\u0007\n� L>�\u0001�U�P1���^�\u001f�\u0013b7�nô��`��>����t;���V�rF�d���\u001de\r&\u0005O�=�\u0016\u001f�\u0011ɡ\u0010�R>&%�\nj\b��\u0000d�H�ݩ\u0006�\u0012e�H�\'Q�bE\u001f_�˓�t��;E�\u000e��C��!Ay2�K��@\u0006��J\u0014�\u0012�\u0010\u0016�\u00142�\u001f1:�rD�\u0019`>>\u0018\u0016�v@�S�\bK\u0007np����R�\u001b��0\u0018\u0016\u0000�oa�Ru+\u0015�J�F#��H42�L�Ķz$RT$F�¾�vuE-/3�+%��EJS⫦�IM\u000f^�>~��4���K��7�W�o3��y��"EY������\u000b\u0015I��J\u0002?R\u0001rÄ�\r^:q���\u001a�/U�j�\u001dXBI\u0017��g�\u0004\u0016P�w`\r�\u0005�t�ғ¤$U�%�^��O�A�R\u0000��Ҧ(��H�j|��x?��Σ�;\u000fx7�u�r��ʍ΋��~�����\r��_;�]i��b�OW���|�z��[տݩ�������|Iu���\u000b��~�\u0002d...
```

was successfully able to save it into a .jpeg...

[SO won't let me add a picture because my rep isn't high enough... click instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Flbq.png)

to find that it instead was a corrupted image that I couldn't use. My app extracts frames out of the camera on the fly and converts them to UIImage(JPEG/PNG)Representation [(see gist)](https://gist.github.com/b-r-o/072ca5d870aa3eae6907f24f754c859d#file-frameextractor-swift). The next best option seemed like to do a direct upload (since it worked in Postman) but Alamofire only supports direct `Data` objects or URL encoded things, and I don't think `UIImageJPEGRepresentations` can be directly sent. I really just want to know how to handle these objects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this one quicker than I thought I would. I placed a logger in my server code to check for the MIME type:

```
busboy.on('field', function(mimetype) {
  // var datamail = /*path.join('.', 'storage', fieldname);*/ './storage/' + fieldname;
  // var stream = fs.createWriteStream(datamail)
  console.log(MIMETYPE: ' + mimetype);
});
```

...discovering a `text/plain` one. I went Alamofire and changed the params,

from this:

```
Alamofire.upload(
multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(compresso!, withName: "test.png")
},
```

to this:

```
Alamofire.upload(
multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
// notice the MIME change
    multipartFormData.append(compresso!, withName: "test.png", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/png")
},
```

And it worked! It was able to safely go through processing and do its' thing. They should really change this in the Alamofire examples, [as they use a PNG Representation and send it without the extra params. (see Uploading Data to a server.)](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-data) It is stuff like that that could potentially keep a dev up at night...